# Excel VBA formulas that used to work now failing

Tags: vba, excel

I have several small - and a couple larger - macros that I've written to make life easier for myself.  They've suddenly stopped working.  I get the error message: "Compile error: Can't find project or library".  The highlight in debugger points to a simple variable, such as the counter variable in a simple For loop (For i = 1 to 16000) - the i gets highlighted and the error message pops up.

If I declare the variable with "Dim i As Integer", it works just fine.  But this is new - I've been using this little macro for months without issue.  Now this is happening in ALL my macros.  Was there an update to Excel that I missed?  Do I now have to specifically declare all my variables (I know this is a best practice, but my macros are personal tools just for me, so I'd like to avoid have to go through a couple dozen macros explicitly declaring variables if at all possible.)

My company uses Office 365, and there was an update not long ago, wondering if that is causing the impact.  Is there a reference I need to add?

Comment: If you look in the Tools> references is there a reference marked as Missing?

Comment: It sounds like `Option Explicit` has be enabled. I would take this as a good opportunity to clean up the code, as annoying as it might be. Experienced VBA developers will **always** use `Option Explicit`. The setting is found in Tools-->Options-->Editor-->Require Variable Declarations.

Comment: @KerryJackson - When I go into Tools>References I don't see anything referenced marked as Missing - but I may just not know where to look.

Comment: @PeterT - When I go there the checkbox for Require Variable Declaration is not checked.  I'm at a loss, I would really prefer not to have to go through all my macros and declare every variable, but maybe this is a new requirement? Or a new bug in the latest Office365 update?

Comment: @Sean nope, I have the latest update and can still, though I prefer not to, write code with out declarations and run them without error.

Comment: @KerryJackson - Now I see it!  Yes, a reference to an Adobe library was missing - the strange thing is that was a very old attempt to parse a PDF into Excel. I deleted that macro this morning based on some other research, but did not see the huge, capitalized, "MISSING" tag in references.  Thank you!

Comment: My company also uses Office 365, but I was able to run a sub without declaring a variable used.  I have version 16.0.9126.2259 64-bit.  If you have an older version then that, perhaps you can try to Update Now.

Comment: Okay, one last question - how do I mark this as answered?  Sorry, been a very long time since I actually asked a question on SO.

Comment: You cannot unless someone answers it.  If @KerryJackson would like to answer then mark that as correct, or you can answer your own question and tomorrow mark it as correct.

Comment: Scott - thanks.  @KerryJackson - would you please answer this question so I can mark it as correct/answered?

Comment: @Sean Sure, I can do that.  Please see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often when you get the error message "Compile error: Can't find project or library", the issue is that there is a missing reference.  The website http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx has some good information on identifying and troubleshooting this type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my recent experience here: this error popped up when opening a complex .xlsb workbook with Power Queries, VBA, and other advanced features. I was getting really frustrated with lack of solutions I found online. For example, the MS help file (accessible from help button on error dialog box) pointed to an instruction list for accessing the 'References' dialog in the VB editor and search for 'MISSING' prefix items in the library list. For some reason, the References dialog, while not grayed out in the menu, when clicked would pop up a window with gray border and completely transparent box (i.e. glitched out). I believe it was due to a faulty Office 365 update. When I had a coworker who is on a different O365 update cycle try to open the file, it worked just fine for her. In addition, she was able to save an exact copy without making *any* changes. Only then I could then open/edit the file without any error messages or disabled functionality. Doesn't make a lot of sense.

Honestly, I used to be excited about rapid release update cycles when Office 365 first came out, but in hindsight they aren't tested very well and often break critical VBA functionality. It's a recurring source of frustration for me and my team that are heavy Excel report users and developers. And I don't have a great preventive solution; just got lucky this time that someone else's install didn't have the same problem.